# SQL query to get data from one table based upon a column from another table?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

In my tables I have for example

CountyID,County and CityID in the county table and in the city table I have table I have for example

City ID and City

How do I create a report that pulls the County from the county table and pulls city based upon the cityid in the county table.

Thanks

Comment: this is sql 101 - what have you tried?

Comment: See this: http://tinyurl.com/d3o2yb4 and this: http://tinyurl.com/jo3lz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is quite a basic question, I'll give you a basic answer instead of the code to do it for you.

Where tables have columns that "match" each other, you can join them together on what they have in common, and query the result almost as if it was one table.

There are also different types of join based on what you want - for example it might be that some rows in one of the tables you're joining together don't have a corresponding match.

If you're sure that a city will definitely have a corresponding county, try inner joining the two tables on their matching column CityID and querying the result.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious common link between both tables is CityID, so you'd be joining on that.  I think you have the data organized wrong though, I'd put CountryID in the City table rather than CityID in the country table.  Then, based on the CountryID selected, you can limit your query of the City table based on that.

Answer (score 0):

To follow in context of Bridge's answer, you are obviously new to SQL and there are many places to dig up how to write them.  However, the most fundamental basics you should train yourself with is always apply the table name or alias to prevent ambiguity and try to avoid using column names that might be considered reserved words to the language... they always appear to bite people.

That said, the most basic of queries is

```
select
      T1.field1,
      T1.field2,
      etc with more fields you want
   from
      FirstTable as T1
   where
      (some conditional criteria)
   order by
      (some column or columns)
```

Now, when dealing with multiple tables, you need the JOINs... typically INNER or LEFT are most common.  Inner means MUST match in both tables.  LEFT means must match the table on the left side regardless of a match to the right...  ex:

```
select
      T1.Field1,
      T2.SomeField,
      T3.MaybeExistsField
   from
      SomeTable T1
         Join SecondTable T2
            on T1.SomeKey = T2.MatchingColumnInSecondTable
         LEFT JOIN ThirdTable T3
            on T1.AnotherKey = T3.ColumnThatMayHaveTheMatchingKey
   order by
      T2.SomeField DESC,
      T1.Field1
```

From these examples, you should easily be able to incorporate your tables and their relationships to each other into your results...